# How to solve ssh crash when pushing from mercurial?

Tags: git, python-2.7, mercurial, openssh, hg-git

I'm trying to help a friend to migrate a mercurial repo to a git one. Unfortunately i never worked with this...

The configuration is :

-Win 2012 server R2
-Mercurial 5.3.1
-Python 2.7
-dulwich 0.19.13
-hg-git 0.8.13
-openSSH 3.8.1p1

The hgrc file looks like this :

```
# Generated by TortoiseHg
[extensions]
hgext.bookmarks =
hggit = C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\hg_git-0.8.13-py2.7.egg\hggit
[paths]
default = git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org:khollande/beeconcept_git.git
```

The fact is ssh will crash when trying to push ! And as i'm not familiar to work with this maybe i made something wrong, i looked a lot on google but i can't find where my mistake is...

```
C:\wamp\www\beeconcept> hg push
pushing to git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org:khollande/beeconcept_git.git
abort: git remote error: The remote server unexpectedly closed the connection.
```

and i have a window saying ssh.exe stoped running...

here is the report of the crash :

```
Version=1
EventType=APPCRASH
EventTime=132288487600471221
ReportType=2
Consent=1
ReportIdentifier=f4f0f313-67a0-11ea-9409-020025bbc378
IntegratorReportIdentifier=f4f0f312-67a0-11ea-9409-020025bbc378
WOW64=1
NsAppName=ssh.exe
Response.type=4
Sig[0].Name=Application Name
Sig[0].Value=ssh.exe
Sig[1].Name=Application Version
Sig[1].Value=0.0.0.0
Sig[2].Name=Application Timestamp
Sig[2].Value=40843497
Sig[3].Name=Fault Module Name
Sig[3].Value=KERNEL32.DLL
Sig[4].Name=Fault Module Version
Sig[4].Value=6.2.9200.16384
Sig[5].Name=Fault Module Timestamp
Sig[5].Value=5010a926
Sig[6].Name=Exception Code
Sig[6].Value=c0000005
Sig[7].Name=Exception Offset
Sig[7].Value=00023858
DynamicSig[1].Name=OS Version
DynamicSig[1].Value=6.2.9200.2.0.0.272.7
DynamicSig[2].Name=Locale ID
DynamicSig[2].Value=1033
DynamicSig[22].Name=Additional Information 1
DynamicSig[22].Value=3a8c
DynamicSig[23].Name=Additional Information 2
DynamicSig[23].Value=3a8ce5a7b3a20f456f83e4393a5aa081
DynamicSig[24].Name=Additional Information 3
DynamicSig[24].Value=ed02
DynamicSig[25].Name=Additional Information 4
DynamicSig[25].Value=ed02022d7ddcf8bbf920c2321db81540
UI[2]=C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenSSH\bin\ssh.exe
UI[3]=ssh.exe has stopped working
UI[4]=Windows can check online for a solution to the problem.
UI[5]=Check online for a solution and close the program
UI[6]=Check online for a solution later and close the program
UI[7]=Close the program
LoadedModule[0]=C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenSSH\bin\ssh.exe
LoadedModule[1]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
LoadedModule[2]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\KERNEL32.DLL
LoadedModule[3]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\KERNELBASE.dll
LoadedModule[4]=C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenSSH\bin\cygcrypto-0.9.7.dll
LoadedModule[5]=C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenSSH\bin\cygwin1.dll
LoadedModule[6]=C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenSSH\bin\cygminires.dll
LoadedModule[7]=C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenSSH\bin\cygz.dll
LoadedModule[8]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ADVAPI32.DLL
LoadedModule[9]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\msvcrt.dll
LoadedModule[10]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll
LoadedModule[11]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\RPCRT4.dll
LoadedModule[12]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\SspiCli.dll
LoadedModule[13]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\CRYPTBASE.dll
LoadedModule[14]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\bcryptPrimitives.dll
LoadedModule[15]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\user32.DLL
LoadedModule[16]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\GDI32.dll
LoadedModule[17]=C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
LoadedModule[18]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MSCTF.dll
LoadedModule[19]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\CRYPTSP.dll
LoadedModule[20]=C:\Windows\system32\rsaenh.dll
LoadedModule[21]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\wsock32.DLL
LoadedModule[22]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WS2_32.dll
LoadedModule[23]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\NSI.dll
LoadedModule[24]=C:\Windows\system32\napinsp.dll
LoadedModule[25]=C:\Windows\system32\NLAapi.dll
LoadedModule[26]=C:\Windows\System32\mswsock.dll
LoadedModule[27]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\DNSAPI.dll
LoadedModule[28]=C:\Windows\System32\winrnr.dll
FriendlyEventName=Stopped working
ConsentKey=APPCRASH
AppName=ssh.exe
AppPath=C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenSSH\bin\ssh.exe
NsPartner=windows
NsGroup=windows8
```

Some help would be much appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

Ok after one day trying to get it working i decided to learn more about this config, so i uninstalled everything and then went back from beginning, so i installed python 2.7 and required modules, tortoisehg (last version), my hgrc file config didn't change, i  tried to push but i was getting a public key error...So i downloaded Putty then made public key that i saved on bitbucket, and a private key that i loaded in pageant (tortoisehg's one), i don't get the public key error message anymore but still :

```
PS C:\wamp\www\beeconcept> hg push
pushing to git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org:khollande/beeconcept_git.git
abort: git remote error: The remote server unexpectedly closed the connection.
```

I really don't understand why it doesn't work now that i understand more how it works...

Answer (score 0):

1. Git repo must exist before push (now I see 404 on read attempt)
2. Git repo must have at least 1 commit